# How to write IPA for a slovenian word Midva?

Tags: ipa

can someone please help me how to write the pronunciation for the word "Midva" that English speaking people will understand?

In Slovene it is [ˈmiːdva]

Comment: But… you already have IPA phonetic notation for this word. It is (almost) language-agnostic, and anyone who can read IPA can read this notation. Can you please explain the problem?

Comment: The problem is that I'm not sure that a general international audience would read like we from Slovenia. I guess it should be something more like mee-dvah ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sine you already have the IPA, I assume you are really asking how to write the pronunciation of the word so that an English speaker who doesn't know IPA might approximate the Slovene pronunciation. And you want a written form, not a [recording of the Slovene word](https://forvo.com/search/midva/) that people can listen to.

Something like "Mead-Vah" might do it. The word "mead" already exists and is close enough to the [mi:d] part of the Slovene, so you're half way there. There will be more problems getting the correct vowel in the second syllable, and people are likely to reduce it to schwa, unless you stress it. The proposed spelling makes it look like a compound, where the second member will have secondary stress (so not reducing to schwa). I think "Vah" is more likely to generate a vowel closer to [a] than "Vaugh", which is likely to be closer to [ɒ]. I don't see any hope for getting the pitch pattern correct (I don't know what model you have in mind). Also, English speakers will use [v] and not [ʋ].

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I haven't thought about the dva part, I was more concerned about the mi part, because I thought it should be something like me or mee. So I gues that [ˈmiːdva] is correct and well understood.